# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'UIKit'

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode11.3, ios13.2

I am getting this error when I build my iOS app using Xcode 11.3 and Swift 5.

> clang: error: no such file or directory: 'UIKit'

[image]

I have deleted DerivedData folder, removed the app from the simulator, ran it in a different Simulator, cleaned the Build folder but to no avail.

Comment: Paste the text into your question, not a photo of the screen that is rotated 90 degrees!!!